# Python if, elif, else does not run if, elif, or else statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I'm using an if, elif, else statement in a method. When I run the code it doesn't run the if, elif, or else, but when I comment out the elif statement it defaults to the else as expected.

```
    def message(response):
        args.pop(0)
        if com_text == "trivia":
            # triviaActive will be False
            if triviaActive:
                # Performs action
                return True
            # args[0].lower() is not equal to 'start'
            elif args[0].lower() == "start" and not triviaActive:
                # Performs action
                return True
            # So it should defaults to this else
            else:
                # Performs action
                return True
```

I added some comments above the chain of if, elif, and else statements that's giving me the unexpected results. Instead of it defaulting to the else statement, as it should in this situation, it just returns from the method without running the rest of the method. I even tried using print statements inside of the if, elif and else statements, but the program doesn't run them.

(edit)
I simplified my if, elif, and else. Even with this simplified version I still have a problem with my elif. Also I want to mention that I use the pop method to pop a value off of args and makes it empty which could be the issue.

Comment: Did you check your indentation? It seems like the last `elif` and `else` are indented by one tab more than needed.

Comment: @GeorgeBou I checked indentation and it's fine. Using pycharm, so it doesn't seem like a syntax or indentation issue.

Comment: It may also be that you're mixing spaces and tabs for your indentation. Python 2 interprets tabs as equivalent to 8 spaces, which may be very confusing if your editor displays them differently (e.g. equivalent to 4 spaces instead). In Python 3, it's not allowed to mix tabs and spaces in the same part of the code, so should probably fix up your code to only use one or the other (and perhaps configure your editor to only use one of them in the future).

Comment: @Blckknght Thanks for the advice. I checked out my settings and changed it, but it didn't work. I believe it has something to do with the "args[0]" in my elif statement. When I replaced it with an actual string and compared it to "start" it worked.

Comment: You should `strip()` the args[0]

Comment: @cricket_007 It didn't work. In this situation args[0] is empty.

Comment: Then obviously none of the if statements will enter... Please provide a [mcve] in your question and correct the indentation

Comment: You have a dangling `else` case here which doesn't correspond to any `if`, `for` or `try` block. Ignoring comments, it's the third `else` from the bottom (fourth including the comment). An `else` must be tied to an open `if`/`for`/`try/except` block, so this code is syntactically invalid unless you're mixing tabs and spaces (on SO, it's all displayed as spaces, so I have no idea what it might have been), and if you're mixing tabs and spaces, the visual indent is useless to us.

Comment: What is your return value? If it's `None` then the first if statement isn't running. Add `print` at various lines in your code to see where it reaches.

Answer (score 0):

Test the code by replacing

```
com_text == "trivia":
```

With

```
True:
```

None of your conditions will run if that does not hold.

If everything seems fine after that change, then it could be that your editor does not like your blank line spacing. As a sanity check, remove the blank lines and see if it works as expected (some editors may not work if the blank line does not have proper indentation, and you seem to have no indentation on your blank lines).

Comment: Tested it out and still got the same results. I believe it has something to do with my "args[0]". When I replaced it with an actual string, it worked. Trying to figure out why now.